# Publishing code in order to improve my chances to be admitted to a CS graduate school

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, online-publication, code

I am 32 years old now and I want to apply for a degree in computer sciences at a European university. I am afraid they could consider me to be too old. That's why I want to show them somehow part of my code and improve that way my chances to be admitted at my age.

I thought about uploading a video in Youtube showing how my program runs and publishing the code of the program in other place, and then putting the links inside my CV. I am not sure how to do all this. My code is an unfinished emulator. It is about 20 000 lines of pure ASM and it hard to read. I feel that I need a way to prove that the video shows a real existing program and not only fake animation I may have done.

- First, I wish to know if it is good to put the links to my code and videos inside the CV.
- Second, I would like to know the best site (and simplest to use) to publish my code. It would be not lucrative at all for somebody to steal my code. Still I think it would be painful to find out some day that someone copied and pasted chunks of my code and said that he made it. I need a basic protection against plagiarism provided by the site. Maybe based on the date I posted the code.
- Third, I am very worried about critics. This is 20 000 of ASM code(only part of the nearly 50 000 lines long project). It is messy! It looks really ugly. It is cool and highly optimized but I know there is always place for more optimization. I love it, it uses lot of SMC and code reusing. I love it but always there are people who could say it is junk.
- Fourth, it is not finished. It works perfectly, but part of the OP-codes are not coded yet. I coded more of them, the ones I think would be used more frequently.

Given a situation like this, what would be the best way to proceed with sharing code to help boost chance of admission?

Comment: I did upvote this. This site dislikes advising on specific situations, especially college or grad school admissions, but this particular question does happen to be general and useful.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  I've done a bit of editing on your question to generalize a bit (including to cover graduate admissions) as well as to sharpen the question, with the aim of making the question better suited for the model of this site.  Please feel free to adjust anything that you feel I have broken in doing so.

Comment: "I want to apply for a degree in computer sciences at one European university. And I am afraid they could consider me to be too old for the study." - well, have you picked a particular programme, and is admission into that programme restricted at all?

Comment: "show them somehow part of my code and improve that way my chances to be admitted at my age" - this reminds me the CS professors at the university where I studied seemed to be split at roughly 50/50 as to whether having coding skills before starting CS studies is an advantage (prior skills, faster learning) or a disadvantage (lots of self-taught bad practices, likely reluctance to learn *why* something works best a specific way when it has always been working somehow without understanding the background) for students.

Comment: I know someone could learn to use well black boxes or objects in programing without knowing how they are actually working, but not in my case. I am using ASM.
What I was afraid of was that professors was going to think about me as some of those students that are trying to show how much they know and even are interrupting the professors in the middle of the lesson to say them they're wrong. Not my case! I hope nobody thinks that way about me, because I will not be admitted.

Comment: @NIki: To some extent, objects are *meant* to be black boxes, so it's somehow fine to use them without knowing what they do exactly. Unfortunately, based upon my experience with students, I am convinced something like ASM *could as well* be used without knowing how it actually works by some, even though it is *not supposed* to be treated as a black box. And while I would not agree with the final assessment, I understand that is what the respective professors who consider prior coding experience a minus are wary of. That notwithstanding ... is admission a question at all for your programme?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If I have to be honest, I am not sure it is good idea to show right now my ASM(AVX, SMC, REG as RAM) work. I have other simpler works(using AS3 and HTML) that I could show. Those are enough to show them that I have some basic idea of programing. But ASM is somehow too advanced(I think). I am just afraid I would not be admitted because of my age. My diploma is from 2000 and I'm not sure it could serve at all. For the case I am not admitted, I wish to be able to say: "I did all that I could do and in the best way, but it was the God's will/guidance and I have to knock on other doors"

Comment: @NIki: The point of my repeated asking whether admission is a question at all is that some programmes in Europe are admission-free, which means that anyone who wants to get in will get in, as long as some formal requirements (graduation from secondary education, for example ... but certainly not age) are met. In this case, **there is no individual evaluation of candidates**. Given that CS programmes usually need no materials or lab space (unlike, say, a chemistry lab or so ...), CS programmes often belong to these programmes. Find out about this first before worrying about age.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm sorry that I didn't answer to you! The worker from the agency that is moving my solicitude said that it will be hard for me to be accepted with such old diploma. So I guess it is not admission-free.
In my time, informatics was not shown in schools. Now almost every school offers it. Younger candidates can pull out a fresh diploma with a note in informatics and I am not a match for such candidates. Unless I show something more(I guess)

Comment: @NIki: I am still not clear about the context, and I think you should add some more information on this to the question. What "agency" are you referring to? Is it someone from your target university? Can you check the admission rules of that university yourself, or are you just trusting in what that "agency" seems to tell you? In the situation I described, at least in the instances I was thinking of, there is absolutely no requirement to have had any prior education in informatics. If the situation is complicated, we might try and find out about it in chat.

Comment: Thank you very much, @O.R.Mapper! It's just I don't want to take more of your time! Thank you for the help!

Comment: *The worker from the agency that is moving my solicitude* - this is completely new to me.  Do you really need this middleman?  Can't you apply directly?

Comment: @aparente001 The agency is moving the bureaucratic part. I couldn't do this alone. They are advising me when it's possible. They can't understand the difference between high and low level language, but for the rest they are helping me a lot. They said me to collect all that I have made in the area of computers and to add it to the CV(I hope this is a good advise). Which is more important for me, Is that somehow, using an experienced man in the middle, makes me feel more confident.(They are helping me to lie in the motivation letter too. It's not my fault the world is false and works this way)

Comment: @NIki: What exactly do you mean by "They are helping me to lie in the motivation letter too."? In the place where you apply, is it the normal procedure for prospective students to involve a third party for moving the bureaucratic part? If not, then why can all the other students do it alone, but you cannot? Do all students have to "lie in the motivation letter", and do you have proof for that, rather than just the agency's word? Increasingly, I am getting the feeling like you are being scammed by someone offering to solve problems that do not necessarily exist in the way you describe.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm not living in the same country. I could prepare it all by myself and send it to the universities, but I'm not confident. I'm not sure my papers would reach the destination. It is a foreign country. The agency already sent hundreds of students to Europe. I have no doubts regarding the honesty of the agency. I first put in the letter that I find myself incapable to work in a team, and I am hoping to overcome that with the help of my colleagues at the university and the pedagogic skills of the teachers. I had to totally remove that and it was important for me to point it out.

Comment: Nlki, thanks so much for explaining.  Your explanation was very helpful.  Now, could you let us know either your country or your part of the world?  Thanks.  //  I am also curious to know, does your undergraduate institution have perhaps an office where some of these types of assistance could be provided?  Could you ask this question in several different offices, if you haven't already?  I wonder if there might be such an office, but perhaps a bit hidden from view.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm not saying where I am from on internet! Many people would segregate me because of my origins. No, I haven't searched for more agencies or offices. I live in the province and in order to visit other agencies I would need to go to bigger cities and I try to save my money for the actual studying. The one I found is in the nearest to my town bigger city and even this way I have to travel with autobus maybe 120km. It is the nearest to me, and worked for many others.

Comment: Nlki, if you're not comfortable giving your country, that's okay, how about the general part of the world?  E.g. Latin America, etc.  (By the way, I recommend using a pseudonym online.)  Anyway, I think I wasn't clear what I was suggesting.  I don't mean look for a *different* agency.  I mean, could you approach the folks at your undergraduate institution?

Comment: @aparente001 No. My undergraduate school's a joke. Not a serious institution(normal for a little provincial town). As example in my diploma is included a discipline that I never studied. I personally do not respect my diploma. I visited my school several times last week to search for teachers to recommend me. I said them I was not an exceptional student and they said: "No problem! We will invent(lie) something for the recommendation letter!". I mean I had the best notes in the whole school, but nothing more, no medals or competitions as I read in the examples of recommendation letters online

Comment: Okay, so much for that idea.  (I attended a school like this in a provincial city in Latin America, so I can relate.)  //  This whole agency application idea is new to me.  I understand that you're not comfortable sharing the name of your country; but would you be comfortable sharing your continent?  I am interested in understanding how these agency applications work.  Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31483/discussion-between-niki-and-aparente001).

Comment: What's SMC? Please edit the question to avoid initialisms that might not be known to the general public (ASM->assembly, SMC ->?)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano "Self Modifying Code"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have a portfolio that should be a part of your application to university or a job or anything. Furthermore you're saying that the working product is a better testament to your skill than the code itself. This is also fine.

The only concern I see is how much work you will require on the reader of your application. If you link to a YouTube video, also include screenshots. If you link to a GitHub profile, consider writing up some basic statistics on the activity or health of your activity there.

Regarding where to publish code, don't overthink this. Github is popular, but a Dropbox file, a Google Doc, a file sharing service, or anywhere else you can post a file will do.

I do not know the proper channel to submit a portfolio or the proper format. This situation is probably documented in the application instructions however, so you should be able to find info there, or reach out to a recruitment officer for how to proceed.

**EDIT** regarding where to post - actually a .zip file or similar may be problematic since they tend to look like viruses to people, who don't want to open them. Github or a competitor may be the best choice since the source code is browsable in their web UI. It is best practice to include a software license whenever you publish (literally "make public") code, even if you think it is unusable. I think the MIT and Apache licenses both amount to (IANAL) "do whatever you want with it, just don't sue me."

Comment: Are you somehow suggesting I could be sued by posting my own code online?

Comment: @NIki Usually, when you publish your code online, you attach a license to it. This license explains what people can do with your code (can they use it? can they include it in their own code? can they make money out of it?), but also it protects you! For instance, if you make a program that calculates the diameter of a cable for house wiring, someone uses it and the house burns down due to electrical problems because there was a bug in your code. A good license would protect you from being sued.

Comment: @electrique I understand it now! The first thing I thought about was the possibility of a false positive in plagiary. As example someone that never heard about Spider-man, writes a novel narrating the story of a superhero bitten by a spider and publishes it. I guess some similar could happen in programing too. That was what I thought about first. I understand it now. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, a license won't protect you from allegations of plagiary, but yes I believe electrique describes the most common risk of not licensing code.

Comment: _Github is popular, but a Dropbox file, a Google Doc, a file sharing service, or anywhere else you can post a file will do._ — [citation needed]  Using Github (or BitBucket, or any similar platform _designed_ for maintaining and sharing code) sends a louder message of professionalism and confidence (because Github repos are public) than Dropbox or a Google Doc (shudder).

Comment: @JeffE what do I need a citation for? that you can share stuff over Dropbox? You kind of need a citation for why posting code publicly is professional and exudes confidence. It might be professional with respect to norms in the open source community, which is not the community the OP is addressing.

Comment: @djechlin The phrase that need citation is "will do", meaning, presumably "is good enough". My comment is based on my experience on the graduate admissions committee of a top-5 CS department; attitudes in other departments may be different.

Answer (score 5):

A second answer to get at the quality of your portfolio.

This revolves around a blunt point that I think is critical to understand if you want a successful application:

### Your code is NOT good. (But that's okay.)

Nobody writes 20000 lines of assembly anymore. For any nontrivial program, you cannot write better assembly code, in efficiency or size, than the person next to you writing C. You can talk about the merits of the code and the efficiency gains you have made that would not be possible in C, but still, a C programmer will be able to write faster, better code, faster, hands down.

If you get into an argument trying to defend the absolute quality of your assembly code,  you will *quickly* find yourself defending, basically, that you're really crappy at writing C hence your ASM is much better. Hopefully you have the humility to understand that C is a good [given we're talking about low-level speed] language you haven't mastered, not a language you have been able to surpass by eschewing. If you don't have this humility, then school is not the place for you in the first place. I personally would be able to detect this difference as an interviewer at a company or for admissions.

### But you have a good story.

*This* is what your portfolio demonstrates:

- You *really, really, insanely* enjoy this stuff.
- You are very willing to make improvements and hacks all by yourself with minimal guidance.
- You persevere to build something big that works.
- Given that high level languages are basically easier to code in than low level languages ("in some sense"), you've proven you'll succeed at learning them.
- You know *why* you enjoy it and *what* you did to make it work.

This is solid application material which is why I'm so enthusiastic about including it in your application in the first place.

**But I think it's really important to understand that this story does not involve touting the benefits of ASM over C.** If you go this route, you will quickly make out-of-touch, egregious technical errors in your application, and steer away from what is actually a **highly compelling** story.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! Please give me a chance! I need to finish to code 4 functions more before I can publish it. This will give it very basic functionality. I just reached a moment that I can't defend myself without exposing parts of the project that I consider I should not expose right now. Those 4 functions could take from 2 days to one week. I can't wait to publish this and have a tech speech with some professional like you! I would be thankful to you if you are disposed to wait.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you actually wrote 20000 lines of code in assembly? People don't write large programs in assembly anymore because it is very rare for a human to do better optimization of a very large program than a compiler. They write assembly in special cases to optimize a small subroutine or to micromanage the execution.

That said, I would propose for you to write a small paper (2-3 pages, or more) explaining what is the purpose of your program, why you chose assembly to do it (maybe to learn how the low level stuff work?), put some snapshots of it working, and how you solved some issues. You can put it up in a repository (maybe researchgate?) and add a reference and link to your CV. If I was recruiting you and saw a paper about a program in assembly, I would check it out for sure. However, **I would never go to read an assembly program...** This solves your issue of not getting the code stolen.

Moreover, if you came to my interview, I would ask you: "Why assembly and not C? Is it a performance issue? Is it a hobby? To learn?". If you add it to your CV, be prepared to defend it.

Second, 32 is not too old to get into university, There were people much older than you during my studies. I'm not sure in which country you want to study, but how competitive is the procedure to enter the university? In some EU countries, anyone can access university and then they have a strict exams scheme for going to upper years. Check your alternatives.

Finally, try to catch up a little bit with current technology. I know you want to go to uni to learn, however, kids now learn Python at high school, and are usually quite skilled when they come to uni. Not knowing about Github or where you can put your code, while having written 20k lines of code yourself, tells me that you are not good at searching things up. Try googling "platforms to publish my source code".

I don't want to discourage you and I apologise if I was harsh. If going to the university is your dream, go for it. But you can start already learning to become a good programmer, there are so many information out there for free, that ignorance is no longer acceptable.

Comment: +1 to "catching up." Maybe learn to write 100 lines of Python and Java, for no other reason than you will actually look stupid if you haven't heard of these languages and can write code in none of the major ones.

Comment: I coded stuff in AS3, VBS, HTML etc, When I start to code something in higher level language, I fell like calling a routine or using a class is just the same as calling/reusing code in ASM, so I often prefer to do it in ASM. I don't know why. I would like to get better in higher level languages.

Comment: @NIki I never said you cannot code in anything else. However, I'm really curious, why assembly?

Comment: It fits well for my projects. As example, in these 20000 lines of code, I never used a call/ret or push/pop. Such way I speed up the program a bit. Often routines are very seamless, so changing few variables makes the routine to do another work. In such cases I use twice less space in RAM. I sometimes modify through SMC key parts of the routines and they do another things, saving such way space in RAM. I admit it takes too much time, which does not repay the speed improvement, but now I am coding as a hobby so productivity is not so important.

Comment: @NIki just speaking as a software professional here...  focus on your enjoyment in optimizing it *yourself*, *even* if it's slower or more bloated than typical C code because it's fascinating and fun and technical and cool. I'm serious. You're treading into dangerous territory when you claim the assembly you wrote is "faster" than what someone like me could write in C with a C compiler. Compilers are *good*, and your argument that your assembly is faster in absolute terms will turn into an argument that you're not a very good C coder.

Comment: @NIki writing 20k of assembly because you enjoy it and got stuff done in it is a story you can apply or interview on, so I'd encourage focusing on that.

Comment: @djechlin When you code something in C, the compiler passes it down to the assembler......

Comment: @NIki I think this has gone a bit out of hand. There is an entire field of CS on compiler construction, there are hundreds (maybe thousands?) of people who spent their entire life in this field. You should spend a few hours checking up on this before you go tell your interviewer that the "compiler passes it down to the assembler". I'm not going to fight this because I suspect you might be trolling us. If you are sincere, please do some reading up. Good luck with your application anyway.

Comment: @NIki *I know that* [technically imprecision notwithstanding]. And when you pass a paintbrush to Picasso he's going to do something better with it than I can on my own. Except here, replace "Picasso" with "thousands of people with Ph.Ds. writing compilers for a living to do this better."

Comment: @NIki  I think you have a strong application coding-wise, but not at all for the reason you think. You will need the humility to accept that writing ASM is not a current skill and higher level languages have effectively surpassed lower level languages in efficiency by *producing better lower-level code*. You are not writing better ASM than the next person's C. *And that is okay.* You have shown brilliance and perseverance in writing a large amount of ASM. That is a story that sells your drive and intelligence. Not the objective quality of your code. Humility is a must here.

Comment: @electrique while trolling is possible....  we're basically telling the OP that a  skillset they spent years developing is, uh, interesting, at best. That's a really harsh blow to deliver and I would be a bit shocked and defensive too. Which is why I'm writing lots of comments here trying to get at what *is* valuable about this unusual coding portfolio, because I think there's a story here that makes for a good application.

Comment: @electrique anyway I rolled this up into another answer so we can perhaps depart from the comments section of yours :P

Comment: @djechlin When I share the code and you see it, you will believe. When I was 6 years old, I drew a sketch showing domination of perspective. My teacher saw it and said it was impossible for a toddler to can draw perspective. That hurt me a lot. When someone is judging me before even seeing my work, just because the common sense says that "a toddler can't use perspective", I feel upset and I want to code viruses and use my knowledge in networks for the wrong purposes. I'm emotionally wise enough to not do it, but out there are many young coders that take the wrong turn because they got hurt.

Comment: @djechlin I admit you tried to not hurt me while exposing your wrong assumption and this is good for you. This here is not the place and the way to argue about languageA vs languageB. When I publish it, you and I we both will have more arguments to argue.

Answer (score 2):

I have written instruction-by-instruction emulators in C and C++ when working on performance analysis of computer systems under development. Based on that experience, these are some questions and issues you should consider if you decide to use your code as part of your application. They don't need to be answered here, but you should be prepared for these issues to come up.

You made two choices that may be difficult to defend, assembly language and self modifying code.

**Assembly language** There are two possible justifications, your own education and speed. Personally, I would never claim a speed improvement without having benchmarked both versions. As I understand the situation, you do not have a high level language version, so you cannot do that comparison.

When I started programming, it was easy to beat compilers by writing assembly language directly. During the 1980's and 1990's it got harder and harder, as compiler optimization improved. Some of the optimizations modern compilers routinely use make for difficult bookkeeping if you try to hand code them. The last few times I used assembly language were situations in which I needed very tight control over what a processor was doing for hardware performance measurement.

That said, if you have a particularly clear, well-written piece of assembly language code it may be worth presenting as evidence of your programming skills.

**Self-modifying code** The only justification you mention is to save space. In writing emulators in C or C++ I never hit memory size problems, not even in the 1980's, when memories were much smaller than they are today. 20,000 lines of assembly language are unlikely to result in more than about 100 KB of instructions. Why do you need to save instruction space?

In addition to the obvious readability downside, self-modifying code may run slower than having separate copies for each function. Many processors have an instruction cache that is optimized for feeding instructions into the pipeline, not for handling changes. Frequently used code that does not get modified can sit in the instruction cache. Code that does get modified has to get reloaded after each change.

Have you measured your code performance with and without self-modifying code?

Comment: The processor behavior upon SMC vary from one CPU to other. In any case self-modified code will be slower than the not self-modified one. That's why I limit the use of SMC in the parts of the program where performance is not important. Usage of RAM space is critical for the project. I have not C version. I understand that the humans need HLL. C vs ASM is like DNS vs IP. And at a latter stage a HLL could be used for the project. Anyway this will never happen, because I've planned to abandon the project once published it. It is too ambitious and I can't finish it alone. And it can't be sold!

Comment: @NIki How would you explain being short of RAM for instructions with such a tiny program?

Comment: I can't do it using only what I have coded to the moment. The concept of the program explained in the presentation will demonstrate the need of as short machine code as possible. While not always mandatory, a shorter program would always be better than a larger one. Shorter programs leaves more resources for other programs to use. I don't see the need to defend this statement. Maybe you all are just testing me to see if I can defend myself in a possible interview with the admissions committee. Shorter programs are better and I don't have to demonstrate it.

Comment: Will admissions committee attack me so badly over my decision to use ASM. I mean it is just a language. Will they be all the time re-iterating over and over again over the choice of ASM over C? I am starting to feel the bad guy of the story and I think I just chose one language over other! I didn't break the law or something! I am feeling attacked and I am worried that they would not even read my presentation and directly jump over their desks and attack me with sticks because of ASM. That's how I feel right now.

Comment: @NIki I am trying to show you some of the questions that are likely to occur to someone reading about your program. That way, you will be able to preempt any risk of attack or choosing to ignore the program by providing the answers in the program documentation.

Comment: @NIki All else being equal, a smaller program is better than a bigger one. In this case, all else is not equal. ASM and SMC both tend to take longer to write and get working correctly, and to result in less readable code, than high level languages. Those are enormous costs that should be compensated by equally enormous gains. Maybe the gain is just that you are fascinated by those techniques and wanted to exercise them. If so, say so. If you are going to claim practical advantages, you need to explain why those advantages outweigh the costs.

Comment: NO No no!!! I think I already mentioned ASM is giving me pain. It is a suicide to use only ASM to code. I even mentioned, I was planning to abandon ASM and use only HLLs from now on. It just happened that I used ASM, because when trying to use C, I was feeling not as comfortable as using ASM. I even mentioned here I wish to become better at HLLs. They will show me only HLLs and that's ok! I just want to show them that I have knowledge and a good logic detecting, understanding and solving problems. ASM or not, it is not relevant. Still it's more advanced than others and that was worrying me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't share the code as part of your application.

Do *describe* what the code does, and the approach you took, and what you would like to do differently if you had it to do over again, and how all of that ties into what you want to do in grad school.

If it doesn't tie in, then there's no need to bring it up at all.

Programmers who are able to document their code are 100 times more valuable than those who can't.  If you write a clear, interesting description, as I outlined above, that will impress the committee far more than reading the code or watching a demo.

If you want to skip the middleman and prepare your own application, you are welcome to ask specific questions about the process here as you go along.

I do understand that the process seems daunting, but Academia can help you and also a language stackexchange site, such as https://french.stackexchange.com/.

One last thing.  Your age (32) is not a big deal.

Comment: +1 on documentation vs. 20000 lines of assembly language code. Also, when I started on the graduate program that led to my PhD in computer science, I had 32 years of professional programming and computer architecture experience. Age should not be a big deal.

Comment: Thank you, aparente! The project does not tie. The university will not touch ASM at all, only highest level languages. And, I myself don't want to use ASM anymore. It gives me all kind of pains. It is very hard to code and debug. I only pretend to show them my level of understanding of CS. Admitted or not, I plan to throw away all the ASM projects. I'm definitively not going to interrupt the teacher, saying "this would be hundreds of times faster done in ASM". NO! I'll most probably not use this acronym at all in the university. I'll do as you suggest!

Comment: Downvoted.  Providing thorough, readable documentation isn't an _alternative_ to sharing code; it's a _requirement_ for sharing code.  **Of course** you should share your code, and **of course** your code should be well-documented.

Comment: @JeffE Is it a problem that it is unfinished? The idea and function are clear, but some less needed functions are not coded yet. I have comments inside the code too. Comments like ";TODO: try to use another register here, because ...". Sometimes I just comment an instruction like: ";xor ECX, ECX" because it is no more needed but It helps me to keep it there commented in order for me to know there ECX has to be zero, but it was zeroed already by the previously executed code. It is a WIP and it could look messy, but the presentation and explanations will be the clearer possible.

Comment: @Jeff - If you think that it is helpful to publish a piece of code solely for the sake of bolstering an application to grad school in computer science, I suggest you develop your point of view in an Answer.